# UILabel.text not updating when didSet called

Tags: swift

I am trying to update a `UILabel` (custom class assigned via IB that's displayed on multiple view controllers) every time an external class receives an update:

```
    class CoinsLabel: UILabel {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

    }

    var coins: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            print("Received update")
            self.text = "\(coins)"
        }
    }
}
```

And then as a test on a ViewController I have:

```
@IBAction func go () {
    CoinsLabel().coins = 1
}
```

The print line is called, but the label text does not change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ViewController` class the IB reference will look like

```
@IBAOutlet weak var coinLabel: CoinsLabel!
```

And in the button action you can simply use this:

```
@IBAction func go () {
    coinLabel.coins = 1 // Not CoinsLabel()
}
```

You can also set up the custom label without IB reference like this:

```
let coinLabel = CoinsLabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
coinLabel.coins = 1
view.addSubView(coinLabel)
```

This will add a label in the main view. You need to set the label Frame to adjust to your desired view.

Hope you understand.

Comment: Can I do this without setting up an IB outlet? The ViewController is just a test, the change coin amount will actually be done with another class. And the coinlabel is displayed in multiple View Controllers.

Comment: This requires me to add the @IBAOutlet into every view controller I wish to put the label, instead of my current method where I just assign the custom class to it in the interface builder.